# AVCapturePhotoOutput to Base64

Tags: swift, xcode, photo, avcapture, avcapturephotooutput

I am using swift to develop an app that communicates with my server which runs flask. I would like to be able to take a picture and upload it in a base64 format. Currently the base64 encoding I am using is producing a corrupt and unusable image. As I am using AVCapturePhotoOutput, the UIImage to base64 tutorials have not worked for me as swift is having trouble converting AVCapturePhotoOutput to UIImage. How can I get an base64 image that works reliably? How can I convert the image from AVCapturePhotoOutput to base64? Thanks for any help in advance!

```
   @IBAction func takePhotoButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
          let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
          sessionOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
        
    }


    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Swift.Error?) {
        let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation()
        var base64String = imageData?.base64EncodedString()
```

Comment: Use `Data`'s `base64EncodedString(options:)`.

Comment: what would I set the options to?

Comment: Have you run a search for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure your photo settings originally, request a preview image by setting the `previewPhotoFormat`. Now you will be able to get the photo's `previewCGImageRepresentation` and *now* you are in a world of pixel data that you'll be able to deal with.